# Implement Reactive Kafka Listener in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, reactive-kafka, reactor-kafka

I'm trying to implement reactive kafka consumer in my Spring boot application and I'm looking at these examples:
https://github.com/reactor/reactor-kafka/blob/master/reactor-kafka-samples/src/main/java/reactor/kafka/samples/SampleScenarios.java

and it looks like there is no support for Spring in reactive kafka yet

I understand how kafka listeners work in non-reactive kafka API in Spring: simplest solution is to configure beans for ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory and ConsumerFactory, then use @KafkaListener annotation and voila

But I'm not sure how to properly use reactive kafka in Spring right now.

Basically I need a listener for topic. Should I create some kind of loop or scheduler of my own?
Or maybe I'm missing something. Can anyone share their knowledge and best practices?

Comment: Did you see a `ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate` in Spring for Apache Kafka project: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/master/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/core/reactive/ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate.java ?

Comment: Reactive support for `@KafkaListener` is on the road map for next year. Right now, all we have is the lightweight wrapper that Artem mentioned. That said, managing partition offsets for a reactive (or any async) consumer is particularly difficult.

Comment: @ArtemBilan thanks for the link, will look into that

Comment: @GaryRussell has the reactive support for `@kafkaListener` arrived yet? I am unable to find the same.

Comment: No, sorry. Contributions are always welcome.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have a ready solution yet but i'm trying this (Kotlin code, Spring Boot). Someone published part of this code snippet here https://github.com/reactor/reactor-kafka/issues/100

```
@EventListener(ApplicationStartedEvent::class)
fun onSomeEvent() {
    kafkaReceiver
        .receive()
        .doOnNext { record ->
            val myEvent = record.value()
            processMyEvent(myEvent).thenEmpty {
                record.receiverOffset().acknowledge()
            }
        }
        .doOnError {
            /* todo */
        }
        .subscribe()
}
```

Look into other stack overflow questions. There is not much there, but maybe will give you some ideas

- [Using onErrorResume to handle problematic payloads posted to Kafka using Reactor Kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62940447/using-onerrorresume-to-handle-problematic-payloads-posted-to-kafka-using-reactor)
- [Continue consuming subsequent records in reactor kafka after deserialization exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62961279/continue-consuming-subsequent-records-in-reactor-kafka-after-deserialization-exc)

Comment: Can you share link to reactor kafka examples or tutorials?

Comment: This will not work. While starting application @EventListener is called, but fails because there will not be ready Kafka connection .